# Mount raid volume command line

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery

I have a 3TB raid, which was made originally with OPEN MEDIA VAULT, a media server. I have recently uninstalled OPEN MEDIA VAULT from the server and installed ubuntu 13.10.

The only problem I'm having is that I can't mount the raid disks and I DON"T want to lose the data at all, it's all my vital information.

Here's what I've tried:

```
mkdir /media/3TBRaid
// And then the mount command
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdd/ /media/3TBRaid
```

This returns `'Mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing codepage or helper program, or other error. In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | tail or so'`

I'm fairly new to LINUX in general, so please don't yell at me :)

The two drives, that I actually want to mount as one are device:

```
1: /dev/sdd
2. /dev/sdc
```

The type of both of these drives are `'linux_raid_member'`

Could someone please help me on how to correctly mount the two drives as one without loosing my data?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as **mount** specified, something wrong with the FS(file system).
Try this:  (**It'll format the drive with ext4 format**)

```
 mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd
```

If format successes 
then try these mounting steps again

```
mkdir /media/3TBRaid
// And then the mount command
sudo mount /dev/sdd/ /media/3TBRaid
```

hope it helps .!!

EDITED:

instead of this():   [follow this link](http://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/08/how-to-mount-software-raid1-member-using-mdadm/)

Comment: wouldn't that get rid of my data though? I can't stress enough that I don't want to loose this data :(

Comment: yes, that would be a problem...
are you sure that it's a ext4 drive ...!!

Comment: on all my other drives, the type is ext4, but on the two mentioned above, they both say type='linux_raid_member'

Comment: but the mount command was for mounting a ext4 FS(drive).
i found this article [link](http://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/05/08/how-to-mount-software-raid1-member-using-mdadm/)

Comment: Yes as I mentioned I don't know Linux that well

Comment: I managed to get it mounted using the post that you sent, although I believe I now have to get all the data off the drives, then reformat them? Is that correct or is there a way of fixing this do you think? I have edited my post with the output of that command

Comment: that would be a better option :)
and make some backUP of your vital data, i mean if it's important,it needs a backUP.
and nice everything worked fine for you ...:)

Answer (score 0):

From your error messasge

> bad superblock on /dev/sdd, missing codepage or helper program, or
>   other error.

That sounds , something wrong with that device. use fsck to check the and fix the possible error.

```
fsck -y /dev/sXX
```

mention your partition there to check and automatically fix the errors in your partition.

hope that helps.

Comment: It's saying `fsck.linux_raid_member: not found`, is there a way of fixing this without loosing the data?

Comment: @Shannon , `fsck -y /dev/sdd` thats enough.

Comment: I did that already, What I posted in my comment is what that comment returned

Answer (score 0):

First check the raid(s):

```
d@monster:~/Apps $>sudo dmraid -r
/dev/sdd: isw, "isw_fhabhedd", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdc: isw, "isw_fhabhedd", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_dhejejifba", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_dhejejifba", GROUP, ok, 3907029166 sectors, data@ 0
```

Then, mount the ones you like:

```
d@monster:~/Apps $>sudo mount /dev/mapper/isw_fhabhedd_SPEED /media/d/SPEED/
```